# Powershell script to convert TIFF images to renamed JPEGs

Tags: image, powershell, imagemagick

I need to convert batches of TIFF images to JPEGs. Can it be done with plain vanilla PowerShell, without installing ImageMagick?

After a little research [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2010/07/05/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-convert-graphics-files-to-different-file-formats/) and [here](https://hazzy.techanarchy.net/posh/powershell/bmp-to-jpg-the-powershell-way/), it seems it can be done. First, by loading a .NET Framework assembly:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“System.Windows.Forms”);
```

But since I'm saving the converted image in a different directory, removing the first four characters of the filename, and changing the extension to jpg, I'm stuck with the syntax:

```
Get-ChildItem *.tif | %{ $file = new-object System.Drawing.Bitmap($_.FullName); $file.Save({ Join-Path "C:\Users\oscar\Downloads\" ($_.Name -replace '^.{4}(.*?)', '$1.jpg') },"JPEG") }
```

I get an "invalid characters in path name" error.

Comment: `.Save({random code here}, "JPEG")` is passing a scriptblock `{}` to the function, not a filename. Those braces need to be parentheses. `$file.Save( (Join-Path "C:\Users\oscar\Downloads\" ($_.Name -replace '^.{4}(.*?)', '$1.jpg') ), "JPEG")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if your problem is situated in conversion or creating the new file name. If file name creation is the problem you can try following. Example:

```
PS C:\temp> "test.txt" -replace "txt", "somethingOther"
```

In your case:

```
Get-ChildItem -Include *.tif | %{ $file = new-object System.Drawing.Bitmap($_.FullName); $file.Save(( Join-Path "C:\Users\oscar\Downloads\" ($_.Name -replace "tif", 'jpg') ),"JPEG") }
```

I also replaced the curly brackets through normal one (at `Join-Path`).

Hope that helps

Comment: As you and @TessellatingHeckler pointed out, the braces needed to be replaced with parentheses. Still need to tinker with the renaming syntax, but the conversion is getting done.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like one liners while explaining things.
This script includes the needed `.substring(4)` for the new file name:

```
[void] [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
$DestDir = "C:\Users\oscar\Downloads\"
$SrcDir  = "X:\test\path"
PushD $SrcDir
Get-ChildItem *.tif | 
  ForEach-Object{
    $NewFileName = ( Join-Path $DestDir ($_.BaseName.SubString(4)+'.jpg' ))
    $Picture = new-object System.Drawing.Bitmap($_.FullName)
    $Picture.Save($NewFileName ,"JPEG") 
  }
PopD
```